# nginx - how to identify the same requests from specific user

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

Is it possible to make Nginx config to count the same requests from specific user and behave accordingly to the number of handled request?

For example, the user makes three requests to the same URL:
http://example.com/file

At first request from this specific user we make redirect to:
http://example.com/file/one

At second request from this user redirect goes to:
http://example.com/file/two

And then Nginx somehow understands that this is the third request to http://example.com/file from the SAME user it makes redirect to:
http://example.com/file/three

So, is it possible?

Comment: do you mean to keep Nginx process stateful by itself? Why not to do that on a backend?

Comment: Anatoly, no, I don't want to use backend at all. I need to do different redirects (to the static files) then one specific user clicks several times at the same link (just as described in example)

Comment: it can be done, but definitely not an easy configurations and its done, it will contain a logic as same as doing it on back-end but with additive complexity, you need to identify the user, and store their counter somewhere with a ttl for instance and nginx doesn't do that, you may integrate redis through lua script, I recommend doing it on back-end.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible but:

First: you will need to define what "same user" means (same IP?, session header? cookie?...)

Second: I don't think that such functionality exists using "vanilla nginx" (without additional modules) **however, with the help of modules like [ngx_lua (openresty)](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxshareddict) will not be hard to implement it using its [shared dictionary feature](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxshareddict)** by having your "unique user identifier" as the key and the request count as a value. For there you can validate the map state to generate your redirects.

Comment: Yes, I had to specify additional conditions. By the phrase "same user" I mean user within the session. Requests are generated within a short period of time, so there is no need to be some strict identification. I just wanted to hand out different static files (related to one common issue) when the user clicks on specially generalized link. And it need to be fast, like Nginx can serve static files.